# How to set different roles to specific user roles on woocommerce purchase?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have six different user roles - A, B, C, D, E, & F. I want to assign specific roles to A, B, C on woocommerce purchase.

```
Role A -> Role D
Role B -> Role E
Role C -> Role F
```

**Update**

Added the code that I am trying, but it is not changing the roles.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'custom_role_on_purchase', 100, 1 );
function custom_role_on_purchase( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $user = $order->user_id;
    $user_meta = get_userdata( $order->user_id );
    $user_roles = $user_meta->roles;

    if ( in_array( 'Role A', $user_roles ) ) {
        $user->set_role( 'Role D' );
    } else if ( 'Role B', $user_roles ) ) {
        $user->set_role( 'Role E' );
    } else if ( 'Role C', $user_roles ) ) {
       $user->set_role( 'Role F' );
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'custom_role_on_purchase', 100, 1 );
function custom_role_on_purchase( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $user = $order->user_id;
    $user_meta = get_userdata( $order->user_id );
    $user_roles = $user_meta->roles;

    $Masteruser = new WP_User( $user_meta->ID );

    if ( in_array( 'Role A', $user_roles ) ) {
        $Masteruser->remove_role( 'Role A' );
        $Masteruser->set_role( 'Role D' );
    } else if ( in_array('Role B', $user_roles ) ) {
        $Masteruser->remove_role( 'Role E' );
        $Masteruser->set_role( 'Role E' );
    } else if ( in_array('Role C', $user_roles ) ) {
       $Masteruser->remove_role( 'Role F' );
       $Masteruser->set_role( 'Role F' );
    } 
}
```